# Strange variable-argument problem in Capistrano Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, capistrano

Hello stackoverflow experts,

I got a very strange problem in a task I'm creating with Capistrano. I'm trying to pass a variable from the command line:

```
>> cap create_dir -s name_of_dir=mydir

task :create_dir do
  printf("#{name_of_dir}")
  if !(exists?(:name_of_dir)) then  
      name_of_dir = Capistrano::CLI.ui.ask("Name of dir to be created.")    
  end   

  full_path = "/home/#{name_of_dir}"
  run "mkdir #{full_path}"

end
```

The very strange this is that correctly parses the variable when I do printf, but parses as a blank(empty) string in the following command. I really find no explanation for this and I'm sure is not a stuping typo or anything like that?

I'm not expierenced in Ruby like in Java and PHP, I'm affraid that there maybe a strange rule?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

A few suggestions:

- Avoid using variables with the same name of internal task variables
- use fetch() instead of dealing with if exits? else then...

Here's the code

```
>> cap create_dir -s name_of_dir=mydir

task :create_dir do
  printf("#{name_of_dir}")
  directory = fetch(:name_of_dir) { Capistrano::CLI.ui.ask("Name of dir to be created.") }

  full_path = "/home/#{directory}"
  run "mkdir #{full_path}"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of capistrano, at least from 2.5.19 which I run now the whole command line argument thing works different now. You call it like this.

```
cap command argument=value
```

And the syntax in the code is

```
ENV.has_key?('argument') and ENV['argument']
```

That's basically it, but you can look at my [blogpost](http://romanalmeida.posterous.com/capistrano-tasks-with-arguments) about it for a working example

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in the second line you are checking if the symbol `:name_of_dir`  exists - not the actual value of the variable `name_of_dir`.

Because you're unlikely to have a filename `name_of_dir` it will count as not existing... and then name_of_dir (the variable) is overwritten by the `Capistrano::CLI.ui.ask` command.

Not sure why but that must be killing it somehow.

Try removing the ":" and seeing if that fixes the problem.